# Is Observable without a subscribe() valid?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I call a service per `RetrofitDataService.getDataObservable(): Observable<List<LogicalChannel>>` to get a data stream.

```
val dataStream = RetrofitDataService.getDataObservable()
    .doOnNext { item ->
        calculate(item)
    }
    .take(1)

dataStream.forEach { dataList ->
    totalDataCount = dataList.filter { it.isFlag }.size
}
```

1: I never `subscribe()` anyhere. Is that ok?

2: Is above code example same as below? I pulled the forEach  into the subscribe()

```
val dataStream = RetrofitDataService.getDataObservable()
    .doOnNext { item ->
        calculate(item)
    }
    .take(1)
    .subscribe( { dataList ->
             totalDataCount = dataList.filter { it.isFlag }.size
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. This is the implementation of `forEach`:

```
  public final Disposable forEach(Consumer<? super T> onNext) {
    return this.subscribe(onNext);
  }
```

It's just an alias for `subscribe`, so yes, your second example is exactly the same as the first.